# DisplayFormat not getting applied on decimal value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, decimal, mvc-editor-templates, displayformat

I have a model property I'm trying to render using an EditorFor template, and I'm trying to apply formatting using the DisplayFormat attribute.  However, it's not working at all -- it's totally being ignored.

Here is my template:

```
@model System.Decimal?
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
```

Here is my model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
public decimal? Retail { get; set; }
```

Here is my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Retail)
```

But it's rendering a textbox with the following value:

> 189.9900

It seems pretty straight forward, but it's not working, and I have no idea why.

**UPDATE:**
Just for kicks, I tried it with a DisplayFor template, and it worked:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Retail)
```

So why would the DisplayFor template work, but not the EditorFor template, when I've set `ApplyFormatInEditMode` to true?

**UPDATE 2:**
Never mind, the reason that worked is because my Decimal display template was hard-coded to format that way.  So my display template also does not work.

Comment: Did you try `@Html.EditorForModel()` in your template?

Comment: Yeah, that only removed the textbox altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Darin Dimitrov posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428289/mvc3-decimal-truncated-to-2-decimal-places-on-edit), and I was able to get it working using his solution:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
```

A bit crude, IMO, that this doesn't work w/ `TextBoxFor`, but at least it works.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this format, it outputs 18.999,00

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
```

Comment: No, that still doesn't work for me.  It still renders `1899.9900`.

Comment: You must be using the default EditorFor template, whereas I'm using a custom template.  Default templates work fine for me, it's the custom templates that don't work, as they have to ultimately use TextBoxFor.  So my answer above, and the question I linked to.

Comment: as @jer says it works in EditorFor but not TextBoxFor

Answer (score 2):

`DisplayFormat` won't work like that; if you manually create a text box for the property it doesn't come into play. It would only work if you did

```
@model System.Decimal?
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)
```

Comment: So does it not work with EditorFor?  I thought that was the point of `ApplyFormatInEditMode`?