# ASP.NET MVC 4 save 3 decimal place value to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to set 3 decimal place in SQL Server 2005.i can set it from only model part .But In sql server set datatype of `Salary` property is `decimal`.

```
 When I set like

         public decimal Salary { get; set; }
```

It would be saved to the database like 21000.000 not 21000. If I put 30000.75, then it would be saved to 30000.750.

Answer (score 1):

I also got stuck in the same situation and finally found the solution. You can override the DbContext.OnModelCreating() method and configure the precision

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity().Property(c => c.AssociationFee).HasPrecision(18, 3);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Apply this attribute to the property in your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0}")]
```

Comment: its not working properly.using this in model class.But whats the datatype i use in sql.

Comment: not sure what you're asking - the SQL Server datatype could be `numeric(12,3)`, for example

Comment: I have no option to set it from sql side.only from model part

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MVC DisplayFormat Attribute:

[DisplayFormat not getting applied on decimal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843099/displayformat-not-getting-applied-on-decimal-value)

Or for display purposes you could use a string and do:

```
Salary.ToString("F");
```

Which would result in the output: `30000.75`

Or:

```
Salary.ToString("N");
```

Which would result in the output: `30,000.75`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , you have to set in edit mode also .

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n3}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

Comment: i enter 13000.340,and click save,at that time it will only display 13000.000.i don't want like this

Comment: i think it would be easy if you will handle it from sql side .

Comment: you should changed your variable type decimal to float on .Net side and it will be solve for sure.

Comment: I use that,But i have no permission to use this.

Comment: change in your model ..make float in model . you can do this . if you don't have permission in sql .

Comment: using float we have get only the entered value.but i want everytime the value will be stored in sql as 3 decimal pt value.for eg i enter 12.3,it will be stored in sql as 12.300

Comment: did you used decimal.round ?? decimal.Round(yourValue, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); , in code do this where you are setting the values in model property .