# How to display number to 2 decimal places in mvc3,C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using String Format to show decimal upto 2 places or simple integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer)
>   [How to set decimal point in 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284682/how-to-set-decimal-point-in-2-decimal-places)

I have Price field in my view. it have the following values `2.5 and 44.`
I want to display this value to `2.50 and 44.00` i use the following code

```
@{decimal prolistprice = decimal.Parse(item.OtherFields["Price"].ToString());}
  $@Math.Round(prolistprice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

in which `item.OtherFields["price"] is a object` i convert it to string and then decimal

but Math.round is not working it shows 2.5 and 44 only..
Can anyone help this

Comment: Why does the title say "integer"?

Comment: You can follow this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428289/mvc3-decimal-truncated-to-2-decimal-places-on-edit

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Math.Round` does just that - round.

To format the number you may use `.ToString(formatString)` like so:

```
item.OtherFields["price"].ToString("0.00")
```

Comment: No overload method for ToString takes 1 argument

Comment: @niico you're probably calling `ToString` on a nullable type.  If so, you'll have to do `youVariable.Value.ToString("0.00")`.  Don't forget to null check first though!

Answer (score 13):

Use string format function

```
1. string.Format("{0:n2}", 200000000.8776);
2. string.Format("{0:n3}", 200000000.8776);
3. string.Format("{0:n2}", 0.3);

/* OUTOUT
1. 200,000,000.88
2. 200,000,000.878
3. 0.30
*/
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you

```
yourvalue.ToString ("0.00");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal dValue = 2.5;
string sDisplayValue = dValue.ToString("0.00");
```