# HTML.EditorFor with 3 decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

How to display the model decimal field with 3 decimal places. Currently it shortens it to 2 digits.

1,237 currently will be displayed as 1,24 ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC3 Decimal truncated to 2 decimal places on edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428289/mvc3-decimal-truncated-to-2-decimal-places-on-edit)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use Data Annotations on your View Model, like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Num { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing the model?

Comment: You shouldn't be using your Model in the view. You should use ViewModels instead.

Comment: So I have to write a ViewModel, even if I need exactly the things I get from the model itself? What should it look like? I want to post all model data I get from the view to the db and dont want to copy all fields to the model again...

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way to do it. You Model belongs to your application's Business Logic, not UI. Let's say that tomorrow you will decide to make a mobile app that will interface with your BL via WebAPI. Different UI rules will apply, and none of them are relevant to your actual data. In your question you want to change the **display** of some property, not your actual data. Your Model shouldn't be aware of it. That's where VMs come in.

Comment: How has my viewmodel to look like, so that I dont have to paste the data into the business logic model? Would deriving it from the normal model or something like that work?

Comment: Well, you could try [Auto Mapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper). Though assigning VM -> Model values isn't all that bad, to be honest.