# MVC (asp.net) issue with decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I am new to MVC5. I just created a web application that has many calculations for different decimal values.

In the database I set `decimal(13,9)` so that I can get maximum benefit of decimal places. 
Now on my development machine I created Scaffolding using Entity Framework for the tables. It works fine!

When I published the website on the web server, all the decimal places in the Views are automatically rounded off to `0.00 (two decimal places)`. I am not sure why.

Can anyone explain why and how to avoid it?

Comment: what is your code to display decimal in .NET?

Comment: DB and .NET are separate things, setting `decimal(13,9)` in Db does not affect the way .NET displays the decimal.

Comment: To format your decimal globally based on your culture, try NumberFormatInfo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits.aspx

Comment: @KhanhTO I understand it does not have to do anything with the .NET
BUT my question is WHY it shows two decimal places in production and nine decimal places on development machine? It has to do something with culture or some configuration in IIS can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a little bit difficult to find the issue. It was due to the default decimal editor template is defined.

I just created a new template in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Decimal.cshtml` as follows;

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
    new { @class = "text-box single-line" }
)
```

Reference: [MVC3 Decimal truncated to 2 decimal places on edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428289/mvc3-decimal-truncated-to-2-decimal-places-on-edit)

Comment: this may not be a solution. As you said, it works on your development, but not on production. I guess the problem is your IIS configuration differences between development and production. (the most likely one is globalization)

Comment: @KhanhTO as I said that I created a new template in this directory. Probably the default template that .Net generates is different in my development and production machines.